# Can I load my existing village in clash of clans to a new Gmail account on the same device?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm playing Clash of Clans on my device. I had linked it to my Gmail account in the beginning. Because of storage issues, I disabled my Google Play. But I proceeded with the game.

Now when I try signing in using my Gmail account, it asks whether to replace the existing present village with the one that had been saved before disabling Google Play. Is there a way to load my existing village into it? Or is there a way to load my existing village to a new Gmail account on the same device?

Comment: Sounds like its not the correct email, so what you want to do is use either the correct one or a new one. Then in order to switch between two different email you can go into the app info and clear the data, when you reload you will be prompted to pick an email to load the associated village. Never try to load a village through the game settings or you could override the current game or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, if you connected your village to your Gmail account, it "sticks" to it. Meaning the village is no longer attached to the phone, but to your Gmail account.

This is what allows people to cross device villages. For example, I currently have my main village on both my phone and my tablet. However, I have found that you can have more than one village on a device. Just go to your settings, and change your primary email address. Word of caution, if you have yet to connect it to your Gmail account, and you decide you want to use your other village for a minute, the first village will go bye-bye.